# How to start a thread when an event occurs and close their handles crrectly

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading

I'm making a service, which is listening on a logon event. If this event occurs, my application should start a new thread, which will do the work.

My question is, how can i start a new thread every time a logon event occurs, and close it's handle correctly if the thread is done working. My problem is, that i don't know how many logon event will occur, so i can't user `WaitForMultipleObjects` because it's first parameter is the number of threads it should wait for.

```
while ( WaitForSingleObject( ghSvcStopEvent, 0 ) != WAIT_OBJECT_0 )
{
  DWORD dwEventFlags;
  BOOL bRes;

  // WTSWaitSystemEvent waits until a logon event ocurs
  bRes = WTSWaitSystemEvent( WTS_CURRENT_SERVER_HANDLE, WTS_EVENT_LOGON, &dwEventFlags );
  if ( dwEventFlags == WTS_EVENT_NONE )
  {
    ShowErrorText( "Cancelling waiting for logon event. Service shutting down.", 0, true );
  }
  if ( bRes )
  {
    // Someone has logged on
    HANDLE hThread = CreateThread( NULL, 0, ServiceWorkerThread, NULL, 0, &dwThreadID );
  }
  else
  {
    ShowErrorText( "WTSWaitSystemEvent failed.", GetLastError(), true );
  }
}//while
```

Could someone help me?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you required to wait for that thread to complete? If not, `CloseHandle(hThread)` on the next line *after* validating [`CreateThread`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682453(v=vs.85).aspx) did not return `NULL`. One way or another, you need to close that handle, either immediately after *validating* the thread started successfully, or after you no longer need the handle. (Side note: If you're using the C/C++ runtime libraries, you should be using [`_beginthreadex()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kdzttdcb(v=vs.90).aspx), btw).

Comment: I think you should use a thread pool instead of creating a new thread at every logon.

Comment: @WhozCraig: Actually i'm not required to wait for the threads to complete. Thank you very much. Post your comment as an answear so i can accept it.

Comment: @Matt: Why would a thread pool be better? Do you know where could i find a simple example for a thread pool?

Comment: @kampi In your case, a thread pool use less resources. Here're an MSDN article on Window Thread Pool API:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163327.aspx

Comment: @Matt: Unfortunately as i can see, i can use threadpools only above vista, but my program should run on XP too. Maybe if there will no support for XP, i can rewrite my program using thread pool, because then noone will use xp :)

Answer (score 0):

If you can use C++11 (starting VS2010), you an use condition variable that will do the job for you

The idea of a condition variable is:
one variable that allows threads to comunicate together.
if you notify it, you send a signal to other threads pluged on it

if you do cv.wait(...) on it, you wait for other threads to signal that sonething has happenend and then you test your condition again.

Here is an example

Server.h

```
#include <condition_variable>
#include <mutex>

class CServer
{
    std::condition_variable & cv;
    std::mutex & mut;
    bool & flag;
public:
    ~CServer(void);
    CServer::CServer(std::condition_variable & cv,
                     std::mutex & mut,
                     bool & flag);

    CServer::CServer(CServer &);
    int Notify();
    int DisplayNotification();

    std::condition_variable & getCondVar(){return cv;}
    std::mutex & getMutex(){return mut;}
    bool & getFlag(){return flag;}
};
```

Server.cpp

```
#include "Server.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;





CServer::~CServer(void)
{
}

CServer::CServer(std::condition_variable & cv_,
                 std::mutex & mut_,
                 bool & flag_):
cv(cv_),
mut(mut_),
flag(flag_)
{

}

CServer::CServer(CServer &toCopy):
cv(toCopy.getCondVar()),
mut(toCopy.getMutex()),
flag(toCopy.getFlag())
{
    flag=false;
    cout<<"Copy constructor"<<std::endl;
}

int CServer::Notify()
{
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(mut);
        flag=true;
        std::cout << "ready for notfication"<<endl;
    }
    cv.notify_one();
    return 0;
}

int CServer::DisplayNotification()
{
    // wait for the worker
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(mut);
        cv.wait(lk, [this]{return this->getFlag();});
    }
    cout<<"Notification displayed"<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Client.h

```
#include <chrono>
#include "Server.h"
class CClient
{
    CServer & serv;
    std::chrono::seconds sleepTime;
    bool finishedWork;
public:
    CClient(CServer & serv, 
            std::chrono::seconds sleepTime);
    ~CClient(void);
    int work();
};
```

Client.cpp

```
#include "Client.h"
#include <thread>
using namespace std;


CClient::CClient(CServer & serv_,
                 std::chrono::seconds sleepTime_):
serv(serv_),
sleepTime(sleepTime_),
finishedWork(false)
{
}


CClient::~CClient(void)
{
}

int CClient::work()
{
    this_thread::sleep_for(sleepTime);
    finishedWork=true;
    serv.Notify();
    return 0;
}
```

Main.cpp

```
#include "Client.h"
#include <thread>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std::chrono::seconds sleepTime=std::chrono::seconds(10);

    //create client and server
    condition_variable cv;
    mutex mut;
    bool flag=false;

    CServer serv(cv,mut, flag);
    CClient cli(serv,sleepTime);

    //thread with the server
    thread thServ(&CServer::DisplayNotification,serv);

    ////thread with the client
    thread thCli (&CClient::work,cli);

    ////join threads
    thServ.join();
    thCli.join();
    return 0;
}
```

Ask me if you have any questions,

Hope that helps